# Hoisting object methods into a class

Tags: scala, macros

I'm wondering if there's a way to automatically uplift the static methods from a companion object, so you can reference them via the instance. Like:

```
object Foo {
  def bar = 5
}
case class Foo()

val f = Foo()
f.bar
```

Extra bonus points for a way to automatically uplift object-methods that require an instance of the class, while removing the instance parameter. (assumes `this`)

```
object Foo {
  def bar(f: Foo) = ...
}
case class Foo()

val f = Foo()
f.bar // instead of Foo.bar(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to accept one compiler plugin [`macro paradise`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html) (which will hopefully be shipped with the next version of the compiler?), you can make an annotation that does all that you want. Specifically (I think this is what you wanted):

- will automatically hoist object methods that require an instance of the class as their first arg into class methods (with first arg = `this`)
- will hoist remaining object methods as class methods (that ignore `this`)

You will have to configure stuff to build macros (or just clone [this macro bare-bones repo](https://github.com/scalamacros/sbt-example-paradise), paste the macro code below in `Macros.scala` and experiment with it in `Test.scala` - `sbt compile` will take care of everything else).

```
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros._

class liftFromObject extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro liftFromObjectMacro.impl
}
object liftFromObjectMacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._

    annottees.map(_.tree) match {
      case List(q"case class $cla(..$fields) extends ..$classBases { ..$classBody }"
               ,q"object $obj extends ..$objectBases { ..$objectBody }") =>

        /* filter out from the object the functions we want to have in the class */
        val newMethods = objectBody collect {

          /* functions whose first arg indicates they are methods */
          case q"def $name($arg: $t, ..$args) = { ..$body }"
            if t.toString == cla.toString =>
            q"def $name(..$args) = { val $arg = this; ..$body }"

          /* other functions */
          case func@q"def $name(..$args) = { ..$body }" => func
        }

        /* return the modified class and companion object */
        c.Expr(q"""
           case class $cla(..$fields) extends ..$classBases {
             ..$classBody;
             ..$newMethods
           }
           object $obj extends ..$objectBases { ..$objectBody }
        """)

      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Invalid annottee")
    }
  }
}
```

Fundamentally, all you are doing is playing with ASTs, and [quasiquotes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/intro.html) make that pretty straightforward. With the above, I was able to run the code below and get the printed output of `Bar(3)` and `3`.

```
object Main extends App {
  val t = Bar(1)
  println(t.inc())
  println(t.two)
}

object Bar {
  def inc(b: Bar) = {
    val Bar(i) = b; Bar(i+2)
  }
  def two() = 3
}

@liftFromObject
case class Bar(i: Int)
```

Note that since this is just AST level manipulation, it may be a bit brittle with respect to Scala's different syntaxes for declaring the same things in different ways...